# Accessing UserDefaults in Swift from other viewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

In my application, I use UserDefaults to store the user's login status (whether they are logged in or not), and their username. It works fine in that when I login, close the app, and open it again my app skips the login page and recognizes that I am already logged in. Although, I am now trying to install a logout button to a separate viewController. When clicked, this logout button needs to 1.) Reset UserDefaults.loginStatus to "False" 2.) Reset UserDefaults.username to nil 3.) Perform a segue to the login page.

Here is the related code from my ViewController.swift file. This is the first viewController which controls the loginPage.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

class ViewController: UIViewController {
func DoLogin(username: String, password: String) {
    //I Am not including a lot of the other stuff that takes place in this function, only the part that involves the defaults global variable
    defaults.setValue(username, forKey: "username")
    defaults.setValue("true", forKey: "loginStatus")
    defaults.synchronize()
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: self) //This takes them to the main page of the app
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let stringOne = defaults.string(forKey: "loginStatus") {
        if stringOne == "true" { //If the user is logged in, proceed to main screen
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginToMain", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Below is my code in SecondViewController.swift, particularly the logout function.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     if let username = defaults.string(forKey: "username") {
            checkAppSetup(username: username) //This is an unrelated function
            //I included this because this works fine. Proving that I am able to read the defaults variable fine from this other viewController
      }
}
@IBAction func logout(_ sender: Any) {
        defaults.setValue("false", forKey: "username")
        defaults.setValue("false", forKey: "loginStatus")
        defaults.synchronize()

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "logoutSegue", sender: nil)
    }
```

When the logout function is run, the segue performs fine but the default values do not change. Can someone explain why and what I can do to get around this?

**Side note, I am not actually going to set the defaults to "false" and "false". That is just temporary for while I am debugging this issue.

Comment: here `defaults.setValue("true", forKey: "loginStatus")` you are setting `true`. is it correct? for the debugging purpose? I guess it should be `false`

Comment: Yes, that is a typo from when I was asking this question. In the real code it does say "false". Thank you. But either way, whatever I set it to in SecondViewController does not appear when I access it in ViewController.swift

Comment: can you set the breakpoint on this line `performSegue(withIdentifier: "logoutSegue", sender: nil)` and type this in console: `po UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "loginStatus")` and see what will it return `true` or `false` ?

Comment: I believe that Duncan C answered my question below, I simply needed to use .set(_ , forKey: "") rather than .setValue. But thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things.

You should be using `set(_:forKey:)` and `object(_:forKey`) to read and write key/value pairs to defaults, not `setValue(_:forKey)`. (Your use of `defaults.string(forKey: "loginStatus")` is correct, however.)

You should probably be writing a nil to the userName key:

```
defaults.set(nil, forKey: "username")
```

And your logout `IBAction` should almost certainly be setting `loginStatus` to `false`, not `true`.

Try changing those things.

Also, there is no reason to call synchronize unless you are terminating your app in Xcode rather than pressing the home button on the device/simulator in order to let it exit normally.

Comment: That worked perfectly! If you don't mind explaining, what exactly is the difference between .set and .setValue? Furthermore, what exactly does .synchronize do?

Comment: The `setValue:forKey:` function is a KVC (Key-value coding) method that works on any NSObject to set it's values. I don't think it works correctly with `UserDefaults`. The `.synchronize` function forces `UserDefaults` to be written to disk immediately. It's relatively expensive, so you should only use it if your app may be terminated before it gets a chance to save your changes to defaults (like when you press command period in Xcode to kill the app during development, or if you use force-quit from the Springboard.)

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the great answer and excellent explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Hey i used the exactly same concept recently :

1) In your initial view, in the `viewDidLoad()` , check whether somebody is already logged in or not, and only one user can be logged in one device at a time, so we check like

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
if defaults.object(forKey: "userName") != nil && defaults.object(forKey: "userPassword") != nil
   {
          let loginObject = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourSecondViewController") as! YourSecondViewController
//As someone's details are already saved so we auto-login and move to second view    
}}
```

2) In your sign in button function , check whatever condition you want to check and then, inside the same, if condition satisfies then save data to userDefaults.

```
// If no details are saved in defaults, then control will come to this part, where we will save the entered userName and Password

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(self.enteredUseName, forKey: "userName")
    defaults.set(self.enteredPassword, forKey: "Password")
    defaults.synchronize()
```

3) On logout button , delete the `userDefaults` and load the login view again :

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.removeObject(forKey: "userName") //We Will delete the userDefaults
defaults.removeObject(forKey: "userPassword")
defaults.synchronize() //Sync. the defaults.
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true) //Move Back to initial view.
```

4) If you are using a navigation control, that you must be using :P then you will surely see the back button which will open the second view if clicked, for that you can hide the navigation bar in `viewDidLoad()` of your login view

```
  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```